# SQL: Get date when cumulative sum reaches a mark

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, amazon-redshift

I have a table in the following format:

```
   APP_iD|  Date       |   Impressions
    113  2015-01-01     10
    113  2015-01-02     5
    113  2015-01-03     50
    113  2015-01-04     35
    113  2015-01-05     30
    113  2015-01-06     75
```

Now, I need to know the date when cumulative SUM of those impressions crossed 65/100/150 and so on.
I tried using CASE WHEN statement:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(impressions) >100
     THEN date
```

but it doesn't sum the data across the column. It just does checks against the individual row.

My final result should look like:

```
APP_iD  | Date_65   | Date_100   | Date_150
113       2015-01-03  2015-01-04   2015-01-06
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Is this even possible?

Comment: Based on amazon redshift tag description,i have added postgre's ,please change if this is not the case

Comment: case when sum(Impressions) over (partition by app_ID order by Date Asc) > 100 then date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with c as (
    select
        app_id, date,
        sum(impressions) over (partition by app_id order by date) as c
    from t
)
select app_id, s65.date, s100.date, s150.date
from
    (
        select distinct on (app_id) app_id, date
        from c
        where c >= 65 and c < 100
        order by app_id, date
    ) s65
    left join
    (
        select distinct on (app_id) app_id, date
        from c
        where c >= 100 and c <150
        order by app_id, date
    ) s100 using (app_id)
    left  join
    (
        select distinct on (app_id) app_id, date
        from c
        where c >= 150
        order by app_id, date
    ) s150 using (app_id) 
;
 app_id |    date    |    date    |    date    
--------+------------+------------+------------
    113 | 2015-01-03 | 2015-01-04 | 2015-01-06
```

Without the pivot:

```
select distinct on (app_id, break) app_id, break, date
from (
    select *,
        case
            when c < 100 then 65
            when c < 150 then 100
            else 150
        end as break
    from (
        select
            app_id, date,
            sum(impressions) over (partition by app_id order by date) as c
        from t
    ) t
    where c >= 65
) t
order by app_id, break, date
;
 app_id | break |    date    
--------+-------+------------
    113 |    65 | 2015-01-03
    113 |   100 | 2015-01-04
    113 |   150 | 2015-01-06
```

Comment: This is just perfect!!!
absolutely perfect!
I just had to add a MIN(date).
Rest all worked like clockwork!
Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

Use sum() over() to get the running sum and check for the required values with a `case` expression. Finally aggregate the results to get one row per each app_id.

```
select app_id,max(dt_65),max(dt_100),max(dt_150) 
from (
select app_id
,case when sum(impressions) over(partition by app_id order by dt) between 65 and 99 then dt end dt_65
,case when sum(impressions) over(partition by app_id order by dt) between 100 and 149 then dt end dt_100
,case when sum(impressions) over(partition by app_id order by dt) >= 150 then dt end dt_150
from t) x
group by app_id
```

Comment: To make it more relevant to the question and also to support the floating point values (just in case): `... case when 65 between sum(impressions) over(partition by app_id order by dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) and sum(impressions) over(partition by app_id order by dt) then dt end as dt_65, ...`

Comment: getting this:
Error : ERROR:  Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause

Comment: Good query, but if `min` aggregate function use in above query, we can get desired result.

Comment: @Cerberus It seems that it is amazon-redshift specific error. [What does this redshift error mean: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-redshift-error-mean-Aggregate-window-functions-with-an-ORDER-BY-clause-require-a-frame-clause) - explanation and solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for desired result.

```
    with t as (select app_id, date, sum(Impressions) 
     over (partition by app_id order by date) AS s from tbl)
        select app_id, 
                min(date_65) AS date_65 , 
                min(date_100) AS date_100, 
                min(date_150) AS date_150
                -- more columns to observe other sum of Impressions
                from
                    (select app_id, 
                    CASE WHEN (s >= 65 and s < 100) THEN date END AS date_65,
                    CASE WHEN (s >= 100 and s < 150) THEN date END AS date_100,
                    CASE WHEN (s >= 150 ) THEN date END AS date_150
                    -- more cases to observe other sum of Impressions    
                    from t) q 
                    group by q.app_id
```

if you want to observe more sum of Impressions, just add more conditions